# Does anyone know which movie has a clever retort about "Good Day / Good morning"?

Tags: identify-this-movie, dialogue

I have read many books and watched many movies, and I just thought of a specific retort that a character made, possibly in the Harry Potter movies (I want to say this was Dumbledore), to being bid "Good morning" or "Good day":

Basically, it was very roughly along the lines of **"Are you wishing that I will have a good morning, or are you stating that I should have a good morning whether I like it or not?"**

I would almost have to re-watch all of the HP movies to find this, and even then, I could be wrong about the context.

Does anyone happen to remember this discussion in any of the movies?

---

Maybe it isn't even in Harry Potter. Its exact form, character, and story has escaped my figuring for the past few days, so I thought I might have some luck here, with the experts!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This quote is from the beginning of [*The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903624/), when *Bilbo* first meets *Gandalf* (a character much similar to *Dumbledore* in looks and demeanor) in front of his house:

> *Bilbo:* Good morning.
>
> *Gandalf:* What do you mean? Do you mean to wish me a good morning or do you mean that it is a good morning whether I want it or not? Or perhaps you mean to say that you feel good on this particular morning. Or are you simply stating that this is a morning to be good on?
>
> *Bilbo:* All of them at once, I suppose.

In addition to that *Walt* was kind enough to provide the respective [YouTube link](http://youtu.be/Z-6d4yZYjFw) for you to see the quote in action (around second 38).

Comment: FWIW, this movie quote is also a near-[quote of the book](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Hobbit).